# Landing a Thermocouple on a surface with voltage present

Tags: voltage, thermocouple, insulation

I am connecting multiple K-type TCs (thermocouples) to an electric engine prototype.  I have had a problem with the TCs having up to 150 volts on them when the engine is running. I don't know the origin of the voltage. Is there a confirmed method of insulating a TC landing without compromising (less than 5%) its ability to measure temperature accurately?
My initial ideas are a thin surface between the TC and the steel. i.e. capton tape, poly tape, or electrical tape.  I will be running some tests this week to see which has the least effect on temperature readings so any additional ideas are welcome.
Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: If it's high frequency common-mode EMI then just insulating the thermocouple might not be enough.

Comment: Maybe you can epoxy dip the thermocouple itself or buy thermocouples that are encapsulated/coated. But yeah, kapton tape should work. There are also things like heatsink adhesive tapes that are designed to transmit heat. Of course you have to make sure whatever you use will remain stable and effective at your peak operating temperature.

Comment: "Ungrounded" probe style thermocouples should work.  They can come inside a somewhat bendable metal sheath (which can be earthed) that provides mechanical protection and shielding. The thermocouple junction is near the tip of the probe, and it is electrically isolated from the sheath. ~$20 to $40 each.  Want better?  Maybe a fiber optic probe is the way to go.  Depends on your budget.